# Use an ID token or access token at userinfo endpoint?

Tags: oauth-2.0, openid-connect

I have a client API, that is a confidential client. When I authenticate with an open id provider, I am redirected to my callback with an authorization code, which is immediately exchanged to receive a refresh token, an access token, and an ID token.

Now, I create a session cookie that has a uuid for the authenticated user. When the user makes a request, do I...

1. Use my access token to call the providers userinfo endpoint to get the user info.
2. Read the validated ID token to get the users info.

When it comes to using the refresh token I see 2 options:

1. After reading a valid ID token or access token during a request, use the refresh token to get a new access or ID token to store at a new uuid, which is returned to the user with an updated cookie. While requiring the user to sign in more, this means the users session becomes invalid after inactivity on their part equaling the lifetime of the access or ID token. This is potentially more secure.
2. Use the ID token or access token until valid and then refresh to get a new one. If the refresh never expires, the user will never have to sign in again even if inactive for a long period of time ( unless cookie expiration is low ) Potentially less secure.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

A few notes first:

- the lifetime of the application session is (typically) independent of the lifetime of the ID token; the latter is just an assertion about the user's identity, it doesn't represent a session
- your first option doesn't work with a parallel requests e.g. when a user has opened multiple tabs to your application or the application uses Javascript calls

But foremost: a refresh token should not be used to get a new ID token, it should only refresh the access token; a user needs to be present to get a new ID token with the same semantics as the original one.

Comment: To be clear, at least for google and the provider library django-oidc-provider, calling the token endpoint with a refresh token does return a new ID token and an access token (and even a new refresh for django-oidc). Using the access token at the userinfo endpoint returns user information directly, not an ID token.

Comment: unfortunately there are providers that do that indeed which is not against the spec but is a recipe for disaster IMHO

Comment: What endpoint is used to return an id-token when providing an access token? And still the question remains, in a confidential server, should one be using an id token or a call to a userinfo endpoint with an access token to assert one's identity?

Answer (score 0):

In short, you only use an authentication token to access userinfo_endpoint uri.

OpenID Connect allows the use of a "Discovery document," a JSON document found at a well-known location containing key-value pairs which provide details about the OpenID Connect provider's configuration, including the URIs of the authorization, token, revocation, userinfo, and public-keys endpoints.

You can research each applications unique discovery page uri from their docs for example here is
[Google](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/openid-connect#discovery)

You make a get request to the discovery document uri and from this document you find the userinfo_endpoint uri.

Example response from [microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/userinfo)

```
GET https://login.microsoftonline.com/organizations/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration
```

```
{
  "authorization_endpoint": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize",
  "token_endpoint": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/token",
  "token_endpoint_auth_methods_supported": [
    "client_secret_post",
    "private_key_jwt"
  ],
  "jwks_uri": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/discovery/v2.0/keys",
  "userinfo_endpoint": "https://graph.microsoft.com/oidc/userinfo",
  "subject_types_supported": [
      "pairwise"
  ],
  ...

}
```

Google's discovery doc uri

```
GET https://accounts.google.com/.well-known/openid-configuration
```

Get an Authorization token. For example pull up Network -> Fetch/ XHR now look around and try to find a request header with the key 'authorization'. Copy 'Bearer {the id}' and put in the header of a get request like the picture shown below.

```
GET or POST /oidc/userinfo HTTP/1.1
Host: graph.microsoft.com
Authorization: Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJub25jZSI6Il…
```

Microsoft Example Postman Request
[image]